# SetWindowDisplayAffinity() causes nvidia instant replay to turn off

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, nvidia

`SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE);` causes nvidia shadowplay to turn off. This code is supposed to make the window transparent to captures, which it does, but also disables geforce experience entirely until the window is closed.

The documentation doesn't state this and any fixes couldn't be found online.
Is there any way I can adjust the code to stop this, or adjust nvidia shadowplay?

Geforce driver - 526.98

OS - windows 10

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I guess Shadow play captures the whole screen instead of one window, so that's probably 100% by design. You should ask NVidia.